# initializing allocating the size of an array

Tags: c, sizeof

gcc 4.4.3 c89

I am wondering why I can't allocate the size of the array when initializing an array of pointers to char.

I get the following error:

```
variable-sized object may not be initialized
```

This works ok. However, the sizeof of will return 4 bytes as a char * is 4 bytes in size. Which is no good, as its not the actual size that I want.

```
void inc_array(const char * const src, size_t size)
{
    /* Array of pointers */
    char *dest[sizeof(src)] = {0};
}
```

However, this is what I want to do is pass the actual size and use that to initialize the length of the array.

```
void inc_array(const char * const src, size_t size)
{
    /* Array of pointers */
    char *dest[size] = {0};
}
```

What is the difference when sizeof of returns a size_t and I am passing a size_t?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, variable-length arrays can't be initialised - that is, it's the `= { 0 }` part that's the problem.  You can still use a variable-length array - you just need to explicitly initialise it:

```
void inc_array(const char * const src, size_t size)
{
    /* Array of pointers */
    size_t i;
    char *dest[size];

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        dest[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: so VLA are perfectly acceptable its only when you try and initialize them. I have marked this as correct, as this is the real reason why I got that error. Thanks.

Comment: @robUK: They're acceptable in the current C standard, and as a gcc extension to the older C standard.

Answer (score 4):

Use `malloc` to allocate dynamically sized arrays.

You must also ensure that `malloc`ed data is eventually `free`d.

- Tutorial-style malloc/free resource: http://cplus.about.com/od/learningc/ss/pointers_7.htm

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I know about malloc and free. However, I was just wondering why I could the following char *dest[sizeof(src)] and I can't do char *dest[size]? Thanks

Comment: @rob: I see. It happens to be the case that `sizeof(src)` is known at compile time, but `size` was not. That is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In C89 you simply cannot do this - *variable sized arrays are not supported* before C99.  Array sizes are required to be compile-time constants.  You want something like:

```
void inc_array(const char * const src, size_t size) {
    char ** dest = calloc(size, sizeof(char*));
    /* do stuff with dest here! */
}
```

I'm not sure that you want an array of pointers though.  I would have expected the following:

```
void inc_array(const char * const src, size_t size) {
    char *dest = calloc(size, sizeof(char));
    memcpy(&dest[0], &src[0], size);
    /* do stuff with dest */
    free(dest);
}
```

**Edit:** *I forgot to answer the second part of your question*.

The difference is that `sizeof(src)` is a compile time expression (IIRC) since it is calculating the size of a type.  In this case, it is identical to `sizeof(char*)` which is probably 32-bits on your platform.  However, `size` in `char *dest[size]` cannot be statically determined. Both are `size_t` values but C89 requires that the number of elements in a statically allocated array are determinable at compile time.  This is why you have to resort to dynamic allocation.

Comment: The error isn't that variable-length arrays aren't *supported*, it's that they can't be *initialised*.  Evidently the OP's compiler supports C99.

Comment: I figured that the version of gcc supported VLAs as a GNU extension.  I should have simply said that VLAs are not supported in C89.  I'll edit in the change.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the sizeof operator is not working as you would expect is that an array "decays" to a pointer when you pass it to a function:

```
int array[5];
printf("%d\n", sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)); /* prints 5 */

/* ... */

void some_function(int array[])
{
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)); /* prints 1, no matter what */
}
```

As for defining your arrays, in older versions of C, variable length arrays were not allowed (note that Visual Studio still implements this old version of C).  You had to specify a constant size:

```
const size_t some_size = 22;
size_t some_other_size = 5;
int array1[5]; /* okay */
int array2[some_size]; /* okay */
int array3[some_other_size]; /* not okay - not const */
```

Newer versions of C (compilers that implement the C99 standard) allow you to specify a variable size:

```
size_t some_other_size = 5;
int array3[some_other_size]; /* okay - VLA */
```

As a side note, no version of the *C++* standard has included support for VLAs.  Some C++ compilers have implemented their own extensions, however (See comment by Groxx).

If you want to allocate a variable amount of contiguous memory in a C compiler that doesn't support VLAs, you must use malloc and free, as kbrimington suggested:

```
size_t size = 5;
int* array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
/* use array */
free(array);
```

Comment: "No version of C++ has ever allowed VLAs" <- totally inaccurate.  C99, the one you're mentioning, does. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#Examples (note the first example).  Caused a few question-marks when I was compiling with GCC and my prof was compiling with whatever Visual Studio uses.

Comment: @Groxx: I suppose I should rephrase that to "no version of the C++ standard has included a definition for VLAs".  It is an extension in GCC and IBM's C++ compiler.  And I'm talking about C++, not C, even though I know the question is about C.  It's just a side note :)